# Spec for aria2 download state files

Tags: aria2

Is there any documentation for files that Aria2 creates for its downloads states? I mean the `*.aria2` files which are deleted upon completion.

I know I can read the source, but I thought of asking here before that, just in case there was any information about its spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, right in [the documentation](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/technical-notes.html#control-file-aria2-format).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that part :)